# Can Deflect Arrow protect you from arrows with a contact poison?

Tags: pathfinder-1e

Deflect Arrow says the attack technically hits but you take no damage. Would the deflector still be poisoned if the arrow had contact poison on it?

Answer (score 11):

From the PFSRD FAQ on [Deflect Arrows](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/combat-feats/deflect-arrows-combat)

> If the attack is deflected, not only does the target take no damage, but any other effects (ability drain, negative levels, harmful conditions, and so on) associated with that attack do not occur.